# Google Contacts API: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ajax, google-api, cors, google-contacts-api

After working perfectly for about a month, I'm now getting a

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here's a simplified version of the ajax request.

```
var feedurl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/EMAIL/full?oauth_token=TOKEN&max-results=50&alt=json&v=3.0";

$.ajax({
        url: feedurl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

Changing `dataType` to `jsonp` doesn't change anything.  In the google api console I have `Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)` set to `https://*.MYWEBSITE.com/*`

My only thought is that maybe Chrome/Safari became more restrictive in the latest updates.

Comment: It seems like Google just stopped adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to responses from Contacts API endpoints. Maybe by mistake so it’s temporary and they’ll add it back, or maybe intentionally. Maybe @eric-koleda knows…

Comment: This seems like a bug, for sure.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one with this issue [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/115701813)

Comment: this random issue just resolved itself.  google must have flipped a switch somewhere.