# Google Contacts API - CORS issue

Tags: google-api, cors, google-api-client, google-contacts-api

I am having a web-app (serverless) that I am using for a long time. The idea is that the app gets contacts from my Google Account, and then I can do some actions by using this data.

Unfortunately, last days I started to recieve CORS errors... I didn't pay attention, but today I tried to fix it. And I realized that all other Google APIs like maps, locations, OAuth work properly.

The only problematic one is the Google Contacts API. I wonder, it's possible to continue using this API on the client side? I didn't touch the code and google-cloud settings. This is a very strange behavior...

> Failed to load https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&alt=json&access_token=......&updated-min=2018-08-09T22%3A00%3A21.000Z&max-results=500:
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://.....' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302288/google-contacts-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115701813

Comment: Thank you for your useful links! As I understand, the best thing is to wait for a few days... Until someone bring the fix or news

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on Google's side (was a bug).